# local min max with hessian

Tags: calculus

Why knowing hessian is enough?

```
I use second derivative test:

If I have a 2 variable function f(x,y) = x^2-y^2+2xy

I get:

df/dx = 2x+2y

df/dy = -2y+2x

d^2f/dxy = 2

d^2f/dxx = 2

d^2f/dyy = -2

So. 

I see that fxx term is always positive. So it is parabola always.

I see that fyy term is negative so, there must reverse parabala always.

This information is enough to understand that the graph will be a huge saddle 
everywhere?
Am I right?
```

Ok. From other point of view
hessian = -2*2-2*2<0 -local maximum. and why wikipedia says that knwoing seterminnat of a hessian is enough??

> If the Hessian is negative definite at x, then f attains a local
>   maximum at x.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix

Answer (score 0):

Negative/Positive definite means all the eigenvalues of the matrix are negative or positive. So if all the eigenvalues are negative, it will be a maximum; if all the eigenvalues are positive, it will be a minimum; if it is a mixture, it will be a saddle point. Indeed, in your question, the eigenvalues are ~ +2.8284 and -2.8284 which confirms that you have a saddle point.

However you do not need to use eigenvalues for functions of 2 variables.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#Functions_of_two_variables